# drawControl not receiving correct QStyleOption

Tags: python, qt5, pyside2, qstyle

I'm trying to style my application though a `QProxyStyle`.

I create a `StyleCustom` class which override `drawControl` to draw my tabs in red or green depending on the tab state, and add the text on top of it.

However, using `option.text` gives me the following error :

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QStyleOption' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I notice here that `option` is a `QStyleOption` when it should be a [QStyleOptionTab](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptiontab.html) if I'm not wrong.

If I comment the `drawText` command, no crash, but the tabs are not colored as they should be :

[image: resulting window]

I feel that somehow, the `drawControl` method is not receiving the options correctly. I have noticed a similar behaviour when trying to draw other control types.

Here is a basic example using a `QTabWidget` :

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

class StyleCustom(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):

    def drawControl(self, element: QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement, option: QtWidgets.QStyleOption, painter: QtGui.QPainter, widget:QtWidgets.QWidget=None):
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel:
            if option.state == QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected:
                painter.save()
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush("#ff0000"))
                painter.restore()
            else:
                painter.save()
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, QtGui.QBrush("#00ff00"))
                painter.restore()
            painter.drawText(option.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, option.text)
        else:
            return super().drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        self.widg_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.widg_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tab)
        self.tab.addTab(self.widg_1, "test1")
        self.tab.addTab(self.widg_2, "test2")

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication()
    app.setStyle(StyleCustom())
    window = MyMainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the casting is done by default in PySide (and also in PyQt) but in this case it seems that not so a possible solution is to do it using shiboken2:

```py
import shiboken2
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class StyleCustom(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawControl(
        self,
        element: QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement,
        option: QtWidgets.QStyleOption,
        painter: QtGui.QPainter,
        widget: QtWidgets.QWidget = None,
    ) -> None:
        if element == QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel:
            (cpp_pointer,) = shiboken2.getCppPointer(option)
            option_tab = shiboken2.wrapInstance(cpp_pointer, QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab)

            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(
                option_tab.rect,
                QtGui.QBrush(
                    "#ff0000"
                    if option_tab.state == QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Selected
                    else "#00ff00"
                ),
            )
            painter.restore()
            painter.drawText(option_tab.rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, option_tab.text)
        else:
            super().drawControl(element, option, painter, widget)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this could be done through shiboken !